# java vs kotlin android development

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

plz someone tell me which language should i consider for **Android development,** **java or kotlin**.
Till now i understand main point  about kotlin that it can handle *null safety* but java can't, but i am confused which language should i use for Android dev, i already completed my java and kotlin.
plz someone help me and also suggest me sources where i can learn without wandering on internet and also share your opinion **if you have to start over, what you do first?**
*sorry for grammar mistakes*

i am expecting genuine answer about language which i use as a **android dev java or kotlin**. devs can help me in clear my vision on these languages.

Comment: Kotlin code should be fully compatible with Java code, so I m pretty sure you can use Java in kotlin and vice versa. Just use either. However for android development, a [quick google search](https://www.xenonstack.com/blog/kotlin-android-comparison#:~:text=Kotlin%20Application%20Deployment%20is%20faster,be%20executed%20in%20the%20JVM.) says "Kotlin is faster to compile, lightweight, and prevents applications from increasing size", which would be beneficial for smartphones considering it wouldnt have as much resources as a regular laptop or server etc

Comment: Kotlin can do more that Java can't. For example coroutine, and declarative UI design using compose, Gradle can be written in Kotlin. Kotlin is the future.

Comment: Kotlin doesn't exist as an Android development language because of it's technical merits but because Google needed a language to replace Java because they were not sure of how the copyright law suit between Sun Microsystems and Google would end. It may be a better language, but that was not why it was chosen. However, that doesn't change the fact that Kotlin is now the language of choice for Android development, so for Android you should use Kotlin. But if you want to learn a language that is more useful in general, then you should choose Java, as Kotlin is still only really used in Android.

Comment: And since you are just learning programming, it never hurt anyone to learn several programming languages. Having the ability to choose your tools instead of being forced to use the only one you know, is a really powerful skill. It even makes sense to learn PHP and JavaScript, just so that you know what mistakes to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Although **Java** is very stable and have a vast community support, **Kotlin** is now the recommended language for modern **Android Development**. Not only **Kotlin** makes development more concise, pleasant, and idiomatic, it also offers some great toolkits like **Jetpack Compose**, **Coroutine** which is not available in Java.

Here you can find more details and Beginners guidelines for **Android Development in Kotlin**

https://developer.android.com/kotlin